# c++ constructor undefined error for gtkmm button

Tags: c++, constructor, gtkmm

I am starting to make a GUI in gtkmm. This is the simplified header:

```
#include <gtkmm/button.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>

class MainWindow : public Gtk::Window
{

public:
  MainWindow();
  virtual ~MainWindow();

protected:

  Gtk::Button m_button1;
};
```

I would like to define my button in the constructor block (not in the initializer part), like so:

```
#include <gtkmm/button.h>

MainWindow::MainWindow()

m_Box(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL,40)
{ 
  m_button1("Button 1")      
  add(m_button1);
  show_all_children();
}
```

But the construction of my button gives an error:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(Gtk::Button) (const char [9])’
```

While if I put the construction of the button with the exact same syntax in the intializer, it works fine (unfortunatly I can't do that because the text of the button will be determined in the constructor).

Comment: That's not construction. You're trying to call the object as if it were a functor. Use a constructor initializer list.

Comment: I want to know how I could do this in the constructor block. Is there really no way?

Comment: I believe you want a constructor initializer list.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
m_button1("Button 1")
```

is not a constructor call. it is a call of an `operator function` with argument of type `const char[9]`

The constructor of the button is called when an object of type `MainWindow` is created.

Comment: So how should I call the constructor then?

Comment: @user1111652 I do not know this library but I think that class Button has a method that allows to set text of a button.

Answer (score 0):

Since the button is already initialized, just set the label with:

```
m_button1.set_label("Button 1");
```

Documentation [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Button.html#ad3f9e419fc13a942f679a8545f0d96b6).